# JaxB @XmlRootElement result in "Cannot resolve xml element declaration"

Tags: eclipse, jaxb

I was using JAXB as DTO to set a stable interface between Server and Clients. Anyways this doesn't matter. What matters is I created a set of classes that result in the following compile error.

> Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace 'namespace' and
>   name 'name' in this context

Eclipse underlined "name" inside quotes as an error. This class is manually created instead of xjc generated.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="name", namespace="namespace")
@XmlType(name="")
public class UserDTO {

    private UserType userType;

    @XmlElement
    public UserType getDTO(){
        return userType;
    }

    public void setDTO(UserType userType){
        this.userType=userType;
    }
}
```

where UserType is a xjc generated class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "userType", propOrder = {
    "userId",
    "userName"
})
public class UserType {getter;setter}
```

So basically UserDTO is just a wrapper that wraps up sub jaxb types.

I'm not sure if it was platform dependent (which it shouldn't be), anyways, just to mention that this code worked perfectly on Netbeans, but when it come to Eclipse, the error prevented the compilation.

The Environment running the project was:
1. MacOsX Lion
2. JDK: 1.6.0_37
3. Eclipse Version: Juno with Package 1
4. JAXB Platform: Generic JAXB 2.1

Please anyone can share some idea?

---

ps: I added the JDK info and Libraries setting as Manuel suggested.

Comment: I wonder if this could be a compiler setting problem.  What are your jdk and project compiler settings?

Comment: Yes it could be. JDK used was javac 1.6.0_37, which is MacOS X Default. Upon setting project compiler, I didn't change much from default, except that I included GlassFish 3.1.2.2's jars. By the way I tried to move the src folder to another computer, it reproduced the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue, you have more than one schema, at least two, both of them don't have namespace, just assign namespace to one of them.

Comment: Thanks Bassel, but can you clarify about where to "assign namespace to one of them"? Should this be done in "UserDTO" or "UserType"? Should I assign namespace to the xsd file or in the Java file?

Comment: Also, regenerate the JAXB classes after adding the namespace on the XSD. That fixed the error for me.